# PHP MySQL if/while loop preventing creation of records. Relates to JQuery multiple image upload

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to get a multiple image upload to save the details of each image to a MySQL table record. One of the fields is 'pageNum', which I'm trying to determine automatically based on a check; if the currently checked page number (e.g. '1') is taken, it increments until it finds the next available one (e.g. 2 is taken but 3 isn't, so pageNum becomes '3').

Here is the PHP code for the upload section.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $upload_path.$image_name)){
        include_once('includes/conn.inc.php');
        $pageNum = 1;
        $pageCheck = 0;

        while($pageCheck == 0) 
        {
            $query = ("SELECT pageNum FROM page WHERE comicID = '".$setComic."' AND pageNum = '".$pageNum."'");
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) = 0);
            {
                $id = 0;
                $id_check = 0;

                while($id_check == 0) 
                {
                    $query1 = ("SELECT pageID FROM page WHERE pageID = '".$id."'");
                    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) 
                    {
                        $id++; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO page(pageID, pageNum, pageLocation, comicID) VALUES('".$id."', '".$pageNum."', '".$upload_path.$image_name."', '".$setComic."')");     
                        $id_check++;
                    }
                }
                $pageCheck++;
            }
            else
            {
                $pageNum++;
            }
        }

    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Currently, the code is not uploading any images at all. If I remove the while loop for $pageCheck and only use the following code, I'm able to upload images perfectly fine with full functionality, except for choosing what the page number is.

Working code (minus the pageNum feature):

```
    if(move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $upload_path.$image_name)){
        include_once('includes/conn.inc.php');


                $id = 0;
                $id_check = 0;

                while($id_check == 0) 
                {
                    $query1 = ("SELECT pageID FROM page WHERE pageID = '".$id."'");
                    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) 
                    {
                        $id++; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO page(pageID, pageNum, pageLocation, comicID) VALUES('".$id."', '".$pageNum."', '".$upload_path.$image_name."', '".$setComic."')");     
                        $id_check++;
                    }
                }


    mysqli_close($conn);
}

echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;
}
```

With this, the pageNum is always 0, but files upload with the correct IDs.

Including the relevant section of the HTML form just to be thorough.

```
<form id="upload" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div id="drop">
            Drop Here

            <a>Browse</a>
            <input type="file" name="upl" multiple />
        </div>

        <ul>
            <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
        </ul>
    </form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've seen how you use $pageCheck. You can improve it if you use it as a Boolean. Start with true or false and check the other one (to be inside the loop). When condition are met change the value.

Comment: So set it to false and for the loop do e.g. "if pageCheck = true"?

Will this fix the issue or just make the check part more efficient than using number increments?

Comment: Only more efficient, after all if you do use an increment to exit the loop on the first time you can use boolean

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'll remember to use booleans in future.
However I still can't make the insert work with the nested if/while loops unless one is removed, at which point I can't figure out a way to automatically give the pageNum a value.

Comment: and to "check" use double == =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay:

As sємsєм Find do use double equal for check ==
And single for store data

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) = 0);
```

Change with

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0);
```

That said, an IF statement use the sintax:

```
IF(Condition){
//Code
}
```

You need to delete your semicolon on this line:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0);
```

(it will become)

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){//Code here}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem in the first `if` inside the while loop:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) = 0)
```

it should be something like

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
```

or

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 0)
```

Comment: I've added the extra = sign, thanks for spotting that. But it makes no difference to the result after testing it with two and three = signs respectively.

Comment: @alex494 you use -> if (mysqli_num_rows($result) = 0); after the = drop the semicolon at the end. A if doesn't work with semicolon, so write -> if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){//Code here}

Comment: @sємsєм Maybe edit your answer and put the semicolon removal in the answer :)

Comment: Good lord, it was the semicolon. It works perfectly after I backspaced that. Thanks, sorry that it ended up being so trivial xD

Comment: If you'd like an upvote/correct answer/whatever then feel free to post the semicolon thing as an official answer, @MarcoMura.

Comment: @MarcoMura Make it as answer as alex told. Your notice is valuable.